# how to disable password complexity check for centos 8

Tags: linux, passwd

I have freshly installed centos 8 on my PC.
I want to keep my old user password.
Centos complains, it is too short (7 chars) and is based on some dictionary word.
How can I disable this check?

Comment: Is it fully preventing you from using your desired password? In my experience they complain but I usually am still able to utilize a weak password on a one-off test vm I create.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate the default password restrictions that come imposed on you in Linux, they can be found at

- **/etc/security/pwquality.conf**

  - `difok`
  - `minlen`
  - `dcredit`
  - `ucredit`
  - `lcredit`
  - `ocredit`
  - `minclass`
  - `maxrepeat`
  - `maxclassrepeat`
  - *there are descriptions for each within the pwquality.conf file*.
- also there can be items in

  - **/etc/pam.d/password-password-auth**
  - **/etc/pam.d/system-auth**
  - *that can influence various password related restrictions*
- **/etc/login.defs**

  - `PASS_MAX_DAYS`
  - `PASS_MIN_DAYS`
  - `PASS_MIN_LEN`
  - `PASS_WARN_AGE`
  - `FAIL_DELAY`

To my knowledge the above has not changed from RHEL/CentOS 7 to 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't

---

But if you insist, you must set the password as root either by logging into root or using `sudo`.  It will still complain about not meeting complexity requirements but will take the password.

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

Comment: many thanks, 
that works